# vagrant synced_folder file permissions

Tags: centos, vagrant, file-permissions, chmod

Vagrant Version 1.6.3

Virtual Box 4.3.12

VBoxGuestAdditions-4.3.2

Host OS -> Windows 8

Guest OS -> CentOS 6.4

This is the content of my Vagrantfile ( where developer is userName )

```
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true

config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/var/www"

#  # comments-> I tried many combinations
# :owner=> 'developer',
# :group=> 'developer'
# :mount_options=> ['dmode=777', 'fmode=777']
```

Now when I try to change the access permissions of the synced_folder(/var/www) or sub directories or files of synced_folder by chmod command,the result is not as expected

For example

```
1) vim testFile.php 

2) ls -al testFile.php
   -rwxrwxrwx 1 developer developer 12 Sep 23 15:52 testFile.php

3) chmod 700 testFile.php
   -rwxrwxrwx   1 developer developer        12 Sep 23 15:52 testFile.php

4) chmod 000 testFile.php
   -r-xr-xr-x   1 developer developer        12 Sep 23 15:52 testFile.php

5) chmod 111 testFile.php
   -r-xr-xr-x   1 developer developer        12 Sep 23 15:52 testFile.php

6) chmod 077 testFile.php
   -rwxrwxrwx   1 developer developer        12 Sep 23 15:52 testFile.php
```

Basically the file is always readable and executable by "owner" , "group" and "others". 
The question is why it is so ? Is there any solution for this? I want the synced_folder to behave according to centOS access permissions.

I am really stuck here for past few days.Please help.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The guest OS normally preserves host's persmissions. Try adding permissions for other users on Windows.